# How to unzip zip file in JCIFS

Tags: java, jcifs

I have zip file on remote server, which I am accessing using JCIFS. I want to extract contents of that zip on remote server only. tried :

```
private void unzipFile(SmbFile zipFile) {

    try {
        String destPath = "//SHARED-PC/reports/";

        int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipFile.getInputStream().read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(" Error while unzipping zip file "+zipFile+" "+zipFile.getName());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But its alwayts reslting in errors 
 1. Access is Denied
 2. I changed given path of dest folder - (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Can someone suggest how it can be done? Thanx in advance

Update:
As per Petesh suggestion I used ZipInputStream to extract files from zip file.
i tried :

```
private static void unzip(SmbFile zipFilePath, String destDir) throws SmbException {
    System.out.println(" Unzipping  ::  "+zipFilePath); //smb://WIN-B3TN6C0DC94/My_daily_reports/19-5-2018/Success/100-Sales-Records-19-5-2018.zip
    System.out.println(" destdir is ::  "+destDir); // smb://WIN-B3TN6C0DC94/My_daily_reports/19-5-2018/Success/


    try {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(zipFilePath.getInputStream());
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        String fileName = ze.getName();
        File newFile = new File(destDir);
        System.out.println("newfile Path  :  "+newFile.getPath());

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        String outputFilepathAndName = newFile.getPath() + File.separator + fileName;
        System.out.println("outputFilepathAndName :: "+outputFilepathAndName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        while(ze != null){
            int length;
            while((length = zis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, length);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Write done // flushing now... ");

        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
        outputStream.close();

        System.out.println("  UNZIP SUCCESSFUL "+fileName);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(" UNZIP ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

But it gets stuck in while loop. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here. I tried using OutputStream and BufferedOutputStream as well.

Comment: All you're doing is *copying* the file, and trying to write it to `//shared-pc/reports/` (the directory), so you're getting a ton of errors in that. What you need to do is read the `zipFile` using a `ZipInputStream`.